# How do I push a file into its subfolder in git repository?

Tags: git, push, subdirectory

I'm quite new to git and I'm facing a (surely) trivial problem.

I have cloned a repository and currently working in one of the subfolders (subdirectories).

The structure is something similar to

```
Main repository
|-subfolder_1
  |--file_a
  |--file_b
|-subfolder_2
|-subfolder_3
```

In the cloned copy, I have created in `subfolder_1` a new file `file_c`. I can correctly add the file, but the problem I have is that when I push the file `file_c`, it gets updated/committed into the main repository and not in the subfolder `subfolder_1`, i.e.

```
Main repository

|-subfolder_1
  |--file_a
  |--file_b
|-subfolder_2
|-subfolder_3
|-file_c
```

With the command `git remote -v` I get the https of the Main repository for push and fetch.

What am I getting wrong?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: the /file-c you are seeing only on remote is a different file, that was created after you cloned, maybe.

Comment: When you say "subfolder", do you mean a regular directory, or a submodule? It's probably the former unless your clone was explicitly `--recursive`

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I didn't use --recursive, so maybe you're right. Is this the reason why?

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you clone a git repository, the "root" folder is the most top folder of all your files.

If you wish to add "New git repository" under the root folder you should add submodule.

In your case you clones a repository, all your files will be added under the root (with respect to their relative path).

Example:

```bash
git clone ....

# This file will be added under the main folder
touch a.txt
```

- Sound like you did not create the file under the folder.
- Check your structure with `ls` or with `tree' command

[image]

**Start reading from bottom up**
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/commands when answering a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)